# Syntax error in DATE_FORMAT MySql Query

Tags: mysql, date-format

I'm trying to select some fields from some table where 2 of the fields are date. I'm trying to make it return them in a different format as the one they're currently written it.

So I tried something like:

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(checkindate, %e %m %Y), DATE_FORMAT(checkoutdate, %e %m %Y), roomid FROM checkins WHERE checkoutdate = '2013-05-19'
```

checkindate and checkout date are in the MySQL date format `YYYY-MM-dd`.

I'm trying to create the following result:

```
id, dd-MM-YYYY, dd-MM-YYYY, roomid
```

I'm getting: You have an error in your SQL Syntax

Comment: wrap the second parameter of `DATE_FORMAT` with single quote. example, `DATE_FORMAT(checkindate, '%e %m %Y')`

Comment: thanks a lot, such a small thing gave me headaches

Answer (score 0):

missing single quotes.

```
SELECT id, 
     DATE_FORMAT(checkindate, '%e-%m-%Y') checkindate, 
     DATE_FORMAT(checkoutdate, '%e-%m-%Y') checkoutdate, 
     roomid 
FROM checkins 
WHERE checkoutdate = '2013-05-19'
```